# How to make early return like other languages on Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to return after valid check then go to other page (1).
However It seems to goes after, then render index page (2).

```
def index(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  unless Model.is_valid!(id) do
      conn
        |> redirect(to: other_path(conn, :other)) #(1)
  end
  # More process are after this.
  render(conn, "index.html") #(2)
end
```

It seems redirect other page at once, but proceeded after.
How can I stop with return like other languages?

Comment: Of coarse, unless else end can work. But I don't want code to be nested by unless else end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elixir doesn't have any way to do an early return. You'll have to use `unless`/`else` or `if`/`else`:

```
def index(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  unless Model.is_valid!(id) do
    conn
    |> redirect(to: other_path(conn, :other)) #(1)
  else
    # More process are after this.
    render(conn, "index.html") #(2)
  end
end
```

If you don't want an extra level of indentation the best you can do is create another function and call it in the `else` block.